# For-each inside of For-each inside...undetermined number of For-each loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a situation where I am dynamically creating tables. There are an undetermined number of tables, so there could be one table or there could be ten tables, etc.

Then I am taking the probability of the first value and dividing it by the probability of all the numbers in its table added ( for example `0.50/(0.50+0.94+0.80)` ) and THEN multiplying it by a number in the next table with the same equation performed on it (for example `0.54/(0.54+0.49+0.32)`), and finally multiplying that number by a number in the next table with the same equation performed on it (for example `0.11/(0.11+0.18+0.72)`)...this could go on for a long time depending how many tables there are.

In this instance, 27 different numbers will be created as you perform this equation until you have used every number combination in the table (3 * 3 * 3 combinations).

Thus, my goal is to create a function that will do this multiplication dynamically, only knowing that there is the class `attributeGroup` on the `div` containing each of the tables (as shown below).

Thus far I have been thinking about using jQuery's each function, as in `$('.attributeGroup').each(...`, and have also thought about putting the selected table rows into an array and popping them out once used for each `attributeGroup`...

**An example of this:**
If you had just two tables, the first with two rows with probabilities of 0.2 and 0.3, and the second with two rows and probabilities of 0.4 and 0.5, you would first do `(0.2/(0.2+0.3)) * (0.4/(0.4+0.5))`, then `(0.2/(0.2+0.3)) * (0.5/(0.4+0.5))`, then `(0.3/(0.2+0.3)) * (0.4/(0.4+0.5))`, and finally `(0.3/(0.2+0.3)) * (0.5/(0.4+0.5))`

**With Oucomes:**`0.17777777777`,`0.22222222222`,`0.26666666666`,`0.33333333333`

```css
table {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="attributeGroup">
  <h3>Group 1</h3>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Type 1</th>
      <th>Probability</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 1</td>
      <td>.50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 2</td>
      <td>.94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 3</td>
      <td>.80</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<br>

<div class="attributeGroup">
  <h3>Group 2</h3>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Type 2</th>
      <th>Probability</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 1</td>
      <td>.54</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 2</td>
      <td>.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 3</td>
      <td>.32</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<br>

<div class="attributeGroup">
  <h3>Group 3</h3>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Type 3</th>
      <th>Probability</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 1</td>
      <td>.11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 2</td>
      <td>.18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 3</td>
      <td>.72</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you have n tables with n rows and n columns.  Each table will have some math perform on its values and then that result is used in addition to some math in the next table, and so on?

Comment: If you had just two tables, the first with two rows with probabilities of 0.2 and 0.3, and the second with two rows and probabilities of 0.4 and 0.5, you would first do `(0.2/(0.2+0.3)) * (0.4/(0.4+0.5))`, then `(0.2/(0.2+0.3)) * (0.5/(0.4+0.5))`, then `(0.3/(0.2+0.3)) * (0.4/(0.4+0.5))`, and finally `(0.3/(0.2+0.3)) * (0.5/(0.4+0.5))`

Comment: This would result in answers: `0.17777777777`, `0.22222222222`, `0.26666666666`, `0.33333333333`, respectively

Comment: Ok, so in basic terms its: tableT rowR columnC probability divided by (the sum of all probabilities in tableT) times tableT+1 rowR columnC probability divided by (the sum of all probabilies in tableT+1).  This is repeated for all values of T,R,C, respectively?  Is that correct?  Recursion seems like the right choice here.

Comment: Example should show expected results to make question clearer